# Java - program works perfectly in eclipse but does not seem to do its intended task when exported to runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I'm not sure if this question has been posted before but this seems pretty context specific and I have no idea what is going wrong.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is, 
- There is a 'server' bit of the program that has the ServerSocket waiting to receive the connection
- The user will run the client and connect to that socket. 
- The user can then send packets through to the 'server' which does some other stuff.

Something to note is that, I am checking if the socket is null, if it is, then the connection is allowed. Otherwise it will just be ignored as only want one user connected at any one time. But, when the user disconnects, the user can just reconnect to the same socket and continue.

This is the receiving 'server' bit.

```
private void shutDownSocket() {
    try {
        socket.close();
        socket = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

class Getting extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        boolean running = true;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("connected");

            while (running) {
                int retVal = interpret((Packet) in.readObject());
                if (retVal == 0) {
                    running = false;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("connection lost");
            running = false;
            shutDownSocket();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Cycle extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2323);

            while (true) {
                if (socket == null) {
                    socket = server.accept();
                    new Getting().start();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

So when I run all my code in eclipse, everything works perfectly fine and it does everything I want it to do. But when I export both the client and the server parts and run them on separate computers, I can connect the first time and everything works perfect. But when I close my client. (Which sends a packet, to tell the server to make the socket = null) and reconnect, it doest work anymore.

I appreciate any kind of help you guys can give. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to spawn an additional thread each time you accept a connection is so that the server *can* accept more than one connection at a time.

If you only want to be able to accept one connection, then just process that connection on the same thread as you accept it:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2323);
            try {
                while (true)
                    processConnection(server.accept());
            } finally {
                server.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void processConnection(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("got connection");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        try {
            while (interpret((Packet) in.readObject()) != 0);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You don't need threads, synchronisation, or anything like that.

Comment: You raise a very fair point. Thanks, it wasn't exactly what I needed but it lead me to my solution. I removed the checking socket for null thing as the cycle receiving the connections was not running when a user is connected anyway. That seemed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need some form of synchronization.

For basic case:

```
final Object sync = new Object();

private void shutDownSocket() {
    try {
        synchronized(sync){
          socket.close();
          socket = null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

on the accept

```
class Cycle extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2323);

            while (true) {

                synchronized(sync){
                  if (socket == null) {
                    socket = server.accept();
                    new Getting().start();
                  }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
class Getting extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        boolean running = true;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("connected");

            while (running) {
                int retVal = interpret((Packet) in.readObject());
                if (retVal == 0) {
                    running = false;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("connection lost");
            running = false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{

            shutDownSocket();
        }
    }
}
```

When running on IDE, there are so many threads running, that the Getting thread may set the socket to null, before the ServerSocket is notified of incoming request

Comment: Thank you for that information, but the server will only ever receive a the connection AFTER the first connection has been terminated and the socket as been set to null. Also, when testing, I am fairly sure I have left sufficient time between attempts at connecting so I do not think it is an issue with synchronisation

Comment: @WhatDoor: that’s the problem with multi-threading: any assumption about “sufficient time” is wrong. Without synchronization, your accept loop might read the old non-`null` value *forever*.